# Limitar quantidade de informações SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Como posso limitar a quantidade de linhas da minha tabela SQL?(sem ser com limit em select, não é como consulta)
ex.: tenho que ter no maximo 10 informações na tabela, porém ela não está limitando, se 30 pessoas fizerem o cadastro, a tabela vai ter 30 informações em vez de 10.

Comment: Não deu para entender oque deseja, o que dá para entender seria o `LIMIT`. Você não quer que seja m feitas mais de 10 inserções, é isso?

Comment: Acredito que você só vai conseguir fazer isso com uma trigger OnInsert e colocando regras para o count. Seu banco de dados tem preenchimento via sistema? Não dá pra colocar essa regra no gerenciamento antes de acionar o insert não?

Comment: De qual banco de dadss estamos falando?

Comment: Qual o objetivo de limitar a quantidade de registros que uma tabela pode ter?

Answer (score 1):

Nativamente isso não é possível amigo, vou te dar 2 soluções possíveis.

A **primeira** você pode criar uma `trigger` que faça a verificação da quantidade de registros e após isso faz a inserção no banco.

A **segunda** é você fazer o tratamento na sua própria aplicação realizando a busca no banco de dados antes de realizar a inserção.

Particularmente na sua situação preferia a primeira opção.